# What is meaning of expression while(n&3)==0 and n>>=2

Tags: java

I find confused with these expression `while(n&3)==0` and `n>>=2` . I am not sure when this condition is executed `while((n&3)==0)` and what happens `n>>=2`

```
public int numSquares(int n) {
    while ((n & 3) == 0) //n % 4 == 0  
        n >>= 2;  
    if ((n & 7) == 7) return 4; //n% 8 == 7  

    if(is_square(n)) return 1;  
    int sqrt_n = (int) Math.sqrt(n);  
    for (int i = 1; i<= sqrt_n; i++){  
        if (is_square(n-i*i)) return 2;  
    }  
    return 3;             
}

public boolean is_square(int n){  
    int temp = (int) Math.sqrt(n);  
    return temp * temp == n;  
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`&` is a binary AND operator. `3`'s representation in binary is `0000..0011`. Therefore, the condition

```
(n & 3) == 0
```

is `true` when the last two bits of `n` are both set to zero. This happens when the number is divisible by 4, as suggested by the `n % 4 == 0` comment.

Similarly, `(n & 7) == 7` means "the last three bits of `n` are all set to `1`", because the binary representation of 7 is `000..00111`. Again, this is equivalent to having the remainder of 7 after dividing by 8, hence the `n% 8 == 7` comment.

When you do `n>>=2`, you shift the number by two bits to the right, with sign extension. In your context it is equivalent to division by four, because the loop stops as soon as `n` is no longer divisible by four.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that n>>=2 is equivalent to dividing by 4.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Although for positive numbers the result is the same, for negative numbers it is different ([demo](http://ideone.com/klxkbp)). That's why I was reluctant to mention the division by 4.

Comment: I'm curious. Is there an advantage of using bitwise & instead of remainder % operator?

Comment: @Amila The advantage is only in readability: if you are implementing an algorithm that treats an `int` like a sequence of bits, bit operations are better. If your algorithm treats an `int` like a numeric value, divisions and remainder operators are better.

Comment: @Amita - probably not.  This looks like a misguided attempt at hand optimization.  There is a good chance that if you write obscure code like this, you will defeat the JIT compiler's optimizer.  In this context, the bit-twiddling clearly does not aid readability.

Comment: It seems the method is only used for positive numbers (otherwise the `Math.sqrt` part is going to barf), but you can always mention the fact that it's equivalent to division by 4 *for positive numbers*.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight it IS equivalent to dividing by 4, provided you're not expecting the "towards zero" rounding that `/= 4` would give you.

Answer (score 4):

- `(n & 3) == 0` is an overly complex way of saying "`n` is a multiple of 4".
- `n>>=2` is an overly complex way of saying "divide `n` by 4, rounding down to the next lowest integer".

So this loop means "Keep dividing `n` by 4 until it's no longer a multiple of 4".

Comment: Yea ... and the corollary is that whoever wrote that code needs to be educated in the importance of writing clear code, and the evils of premature optimization.

Answer (score 0):

> `&` is a bitwise AND

Bitwise operator works on bits in case of `AND` it return 1 only if both operands are 1, otherwise zero.

Suppose n = 4 in your case then

`n & 3` would be `100 & 011` will give you `000` ie `0`

> `>>` bitshift operator

`n >> 2` would be `100 >> 2` give you `001` ie `1`

shifting each bit to the right 2 times.

You can read about the more in [Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)